# file hidden flex vista

Tags: apache-flex, file, windows-vista, hidden

is there any way to create a file as a hidden in vista, xp, 2000,98 ,macintosh from flex
by using var file:File = new File(""); or any other way

Comment: flex means flex AIR application from client side not from server side
pls help me

Answer (score 0):

On a mac you can make any file hidden by prepending the filename with a "."  So, the file `afile.txt` is visible, but `.afile.txt` is hidden.

I don't know on windows.